# PowerShell: Using Microsoft Windows 10 Built-in OCR (Windows.Media.Ocr.dll) with Inline CSharp

Tags: c#, powershell

While I've found 2 ways to use Win10's OCR in PowerShell, the issue is that I want to process the list BoundingRect provided by OcrLine.Words, and C# seems consistently 3 times faster than PowerShell.  Now I could do the OCR in PowerShell and call C# to process the BoundingRects, but it just seems like it would be a lot cleaner to do both in C#.

But every attempt to reference the Windows.Media.Ocr assembly has failed to even find the assembly, with the exception of the following code - which complains it can't open it.

```
$OCRDLL = (Get-Command -Name "Windows.Media.Ocr.DLL" -CommandType 'Application' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Source
if($OCRDLL) {
    $Assemblies = ($OCRDLL)
    Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assemblies -Language CSharp @"
using Windows.Media.Ocr;

public static class OCR {
    public static async string RecognizeOCR(string fullFilePath) {
        var ocrEngine = Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(new Windows.Globalization.Language("en"));
    }
}
"@
    $Temp = [OCR]::RecognizeOCR( "$PSScriptRoot\20000111-p001.jpg")
    $Temp
}
```

Error:

```
Add-Type : (0) : Metadata file 'c:\Windows\System32\Windows.Media.Ocr.dll' could not be
    opened -- 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 
    'd -- 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. '
```

I guess I need someone to either tell me how it's done, or to tell me it can't be done.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: This sounds like it's relevant: "APIs in the Windows.Media.Ocr namespace are only supported for desktop apps with_ package identity_. This means that the app is installed and run from an MSIX package." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Ocr

Comment: @mklement0, so, PowerShell 5.1 is a desktop app with package identity?  But PowerShell's C# doesn't have package identity?  Then is it possible to [grand identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/grant-identity-to-nonpackaged-apps) to PowerShell's C#.  But even is the answer is yes to all 3 questions, it looks like more work than it is worth.  Thanks you for the response and for shedding some light on the possible cause.

Comment: Glad to hear the pointer was at least somewhat helpful. I'm out of my depth with respect to your questions; if you research them yourself and find answers, please share.